# Reading in a file in 1kB blocks and writing to another file with cstdio

Tags: c++, io

I'm trying to write a simple program that reads data from a file (input) in blocks of 1024 bytes, then writes the data to another file (output). The program works so far, but the problem I've run into is that if it reaches the end of the file and the last read isn't a neat block of 1024 bytes then it outputs garbage data for the rest of the array. I've got this working fine using fstream functions, but when I use cstdio functions (the assignment is to use fread and fwrite) is when I get the problem. Here's my code thus far:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    FILE* fin;
    FILE* fout;
    char block[1024];


    fin = fopen("input", "r");
    fout = fopen("output", "w+");

    while (!feof(fin))
    {
        fread(block,1024,1,fin);
        fwrite(block,1,1024,fout);
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I can't seem to find any information about it on cplusplus.com and I can't figure out how to word the question on google. I appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: why stdio instead of streams? (not that it's related to your bug)

Answer (score 4):

You have your `size` and `count` arguments around the wrong way in the `fread`. If you attempt to `fread` one item of size 1K and there's only fifteen bytes left in the file, you'll get *nothing* and the file will forever remain unread. That is, until your `fwrite` calls fill up the disk, *then* you'll know about it.

In other words, you'll never see that last fifteen bytes. That's because, while `fread` will happily give you less *elements* than you ask for, it will only give you whole elements, not partial ones.

What you need to do is to try and read 1024 items of size one byte each (rather than one item of 1024 bytes).

`fread` also returns the *actual* number of items read (which, as noted above, may be less than what you asked for) and *that's* what you should pass to `fwrite` <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
size_t bytCount;
while (! feof (fin)) {
    bytCount = fread (block, 1, sizeof(block), fin);
    fwrite (block, 1, bytCount, fout);
}
```

You'll see I've also changed the magic number `1024` to `sizeof(block)` - this will minimise the source code changes needed if you ever up the buffer size.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you wanted to be truly robust, `fwrite` also returns the number of items written, which may be less than what you asked for. Perfect code would check this condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

1024 is your buffer size. fread returns the actual number of bytes read from the file (put in the buffer). Make use of it.